# "Assignment problems" which does not require to find min/max but just a valid assignment?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I was reading a problem which seemed to be an assignment problem to me .Here is the abstract:
A company has N jobs with it.N candidates have come to apply for it but at different times.

Given an NxN matrix in which cell (i,j) denotes the time when job-seeker i approaches for jth to the  company. You have to find a valid **one to one assignment** . if a job is assigned to a candidate then that candidate does not look for more jobs.No two candidates must be given the same job.Also **at any given moment no two candidates must be at the same job office**.Output should be any one permutation which satisfies the above constraints.

eg:
Input:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Output:

3 2 1

Explantion: At time =1sec 1st candidate goes to the first job.Then at time=2sec to the second job.But he is finally assigned the job 3 at time 3.Then at 5th sec job 2 will be assigned to 2nd cand. So he will not go for the job 3 at time =6.Then finally the 1st job will be assigned to the 3rd cand at t=7.

Note that any other permutation is incorrect.For output (1 2 3) will be wrong because the 1st candidate will be assigned the first job.So He will not look for the jobs 2 and 3 .But at the 4 sec the 2nd candidate will also apply for the 1st job  which already has the 1st person in the office.

My question is that how to deal with such assignment problems ??

Answer (score 0):

If you order the (i, j) by time, Now which ever person applied for a job last, give that person that job. There will still be someone available for all other jobs at an earlier time (because otherwise it wouldn't have been the maximum time).
Now keep repeating this you will get an assignment fairly quickly:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]

dictionary = {}
for person in range(3):
    for job in range(3):
        time = matrix[person][job]
        dictionary[time] = (person, job)

ordered_time = sorted(dictionary.keys(), reverse=True)

taken_job = set()
taken_person = set()
assignment = []
for time in ordered_time:
    person, job = dictionary[time]
    if person not in taken_person and job not in taken_job:
        assignment.append("t=%s, i=%s, j=%s" % (time, person, job))
        taken_job.add(job)
        taken_person.add(person)

print(assignment)
#['t=9, i=2, j=2', 't=5, i=1, j=1', 't=1, i=0, j=0']
```

Comment: But this is not what the question asks.As I had mentioned that no two people should be in the same office together.So when at t=4 second person goes to the office of the 1st job it is not allowed as it is already occupied by 1st person

Comment: right, i get it.. hmm i'll think about it and hopefully update this answer later.

Answer (score 0):

This is the BLOCKING problem from CodeChef August Challenge programming competition which is currently running.  It is against the rules to ask for these sort of hints while the competition is running.

http://www.codechef.com/AUG12/problems/BLOCKING

Once the compeititon has completed on the weekend you will be able to get your answer by looking at other competitors answers.